How to list every methods/properties of an object?
I can't list every keys of an object, this object is from Chrome API. I'm developing an extension and I'm using chrome API. Since chrome is an object that contains useful methods, I could just console.log(Object.keys(chrome)) on a background script and see every keys of that object.
That worked just fine, however, the logged keys are incomplete. Specifically, chrome.management have a method called getAll, but the logged result only have these keys:
Array(7)
   0: "getPermissionWarningsByManifest"
   1: "getSelf"
   2: "uninstallSelf"
   3: "ExtensionDisabledReason"
   4: "ExtensionInstallType"
   5: "ExtensionType"
   6: "LaunchType"length: 
   7[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. I called the command in a right environment (background) and I'm properly logging the data. Any help would be appreciated!

Object.keys only returns the own, enumerable properties. It doesn't return the properties inherited from prototypes or properties that are non-enumerable.

Use Object.getOwnPropertyNames() to include the non-enumerable properties.

I don't think there's any built-in function that will get all the inherited properties.

Object.getOwnPropertyNames() logs the similar result.

Then it must be inherited. See the linked function for how to get inherited properties.

I tried the solutions from the answer and getAll is still nowhere to be found. I'm starting to think that this is specific to Chrome.

This may be implemented using a proxy, so methods are looked up dynamically rather than being ordinary properties. In general, built-in browser objects sometimes have special behavior.

I'm so stupid. I forgot to set the "management" permission. That's why it's not returning keys that requires a permission. Thank you so much, I wouldn't realize it without your help.
